# How to install impala on an already running hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

I have an already up and running Hadoop, 5-node cluster. I want to install Impala on the HDFS cluster without the Cloudera Manager. Can anyone supposedly guide me through the process or a link of the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: [Cloudera Non-CM Impala Installation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-0-0/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_noncm_installation.html)